# How to use a array variable at: WHERE meta_id IN ( ... ) in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

now have array is:
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5....)

and i can use ... WHERE meta_id IN (1,2,3,4,5....) to get mysql data,

but how to replace the number to $arr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `JOIN`

```
$array = array('1', '2', '3');
$arr_ID = join(',', $array);  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE id IN ($arr_ID)";
```

- [PHP JOIN (*alias of implode()*)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php)

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$string = implode(',', $arr);
$sql = sprintf('SELECT `foo` FROM `table` WHERE `meta_id` IN (%s)', $string);
```

The longer answer:

You should look into using parameters in your query, to avoid SQL injections. In your example, you  do have an "hardcoded" array, but if there's user input to be used in the `IN` clause... well, then your best bet would be to use parameters ([as seen on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)):

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$questionMarkArray = array();

foreach($arr as $item) {
    $questionMarkArray[] = '?';
}

$string = implode(',', $questionMarkArray);
$sql = sprintf('SELECT `foo` FROM `table` WHERE `meta_id` IN (%s)', $string);
$statement = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute($arr);
$results = $statement->fetchAll();
```

That way, you'll get rid of the possibility of SQL injections and whatnot.

Also, as I haven't really been writing php for a year or two, there's probably a better way to create the question marks (however, appending to a string manually is way uglier imo).